# Radiobuttons with Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I have following code that makes two `radio buttons` to form. Problem is that both `radio buttons` can be selected same time. How to fix my code?

```
{
   xtype: 'radio',
   checked: true,
   fieldLabel: '<?= $this->fail_select ?>',
   boxLabel: '<?= $this->i_am_not ?>',
   name: 'option1',
   inputValue: 'option1',
   height:20
   }, {
        xtype: 'radio',
        fieldLabel: '',
        labelSeparator: '',
        boxLabel: '<?= $this->something_else ?>',
        name: 'option2',
        inputValue: 'option2',
        height:32
   }
```

Comment: give common name to both of them. e.g. `name:'option1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is good example of radiogroup 
[Sencha example](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.form.RadioGroup.1/)